# Как создать динамический массив из комплексного типа?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Как создать динамический массив из комплексного типа?

```
int main()
{
    double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
    double complex z2 = 1.0 - 4.0 * I;
}
```

Comment: нужно показать код, даже если он и с ошибкой

Comment: В каком месте у вас возникли сложности? Опишите подробнее. Приложите код к вопросу.

Comment: int main() {
 double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
 double complex z2 = 1.0 - 4.0 * I;
}
Например этот , визуалка 15года пишет что не хватает ; после z1 и z2 .

Comment: `#include <complex.h>` забыли?

Comment: нет, я подключил.
Это как то зависит от версии визуалки ?

Comment: "версии визуалки"???

Comment: "Visual studio"

Comment: а VS разве вообще умеет `complex.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот, в VC++ 2017 (в режиме C):

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    _Dcomplex *d = malloc(sizeof(_Dcomplex)*10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        d[i] = _DCOMPLEX_(i,10-i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d   %lf\n",i,cabs(d[i]));

    free(d);

}
```

Устроит?

Comment: Все верно. `complex.h` в его классическом виде не поддерживается в VS. Майкрософт решили создать свою собственную реализацию комплексных чисел. Поэтому нужно пользоваться таким вот предложенным функционалом.